# Correct way to clone project, target, storyboard IOS - xcode

Tags: xcode, storyboard, duplicates, project

I have a completed application in a project. Now, I need to make an application exactly the same but with some color changes and generate new certificates to push.
What would be the correct way?
I know I have to double the storyboard and create a new target but if someone could tell me how is the correct way would appreciate.

Comment: can u show some code

Comment: i cant show because not is mine... is a simple project, with 1 storyboard... i need get 2 targets more.. with the same classes and new storyboards with different colors...